# How to create criteria for multiple @One to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and i have some troubles creating criteria to get data from database. So here we go: I have the following tables in the database:
[image]
User entity

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "usertbl")
 public class User implements DomainModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private Date dob;
    private String email;
    private String phonenumber;
    private int rank;
    private String paypalAccount;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

    //getters & setters
}
```

Auction entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auctiontbl")
public class Auction implements DomainModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemid")
    @JsonBackReference
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)  
    private Item item;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private Float reservedPrice;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Item entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "itemtbl")
public class Item implements DomainModel {



    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    private String picture1;
    private String picture2;
    private String picture3;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryid", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Category category;

    private Status status;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "item")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
    @JsonManagedReference
    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Auction> auctions = new HashSet<Auction>();

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then i have to create a query to get all auctions that are matching a certain criteria : to have price between 2 bounds - restriction for entity auction , to have a specific description - restriction for the entity item and to belong to a certain category - restriction for entity category. And i am not able to do that correctly and my application fails with the error: `could not resolve property: price of: online_auction.domain_model.Item;` This is what I've tried so far:

```
@Override
public List<Aution> getAuctionsByRefineAndSearch(Integer categoryId,
        String text, Float startPrice, Float endPrice)
        throws EntityNotFoundException {
    List<Auction> foundAuctions = new ArrayList<Auction>();
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Auction.class).createCriteria("item");

    // check if the parameters are not null
    // check if the text is not null
    if (text != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions
                .disjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + text + "%",
                        MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                .add(Restrictions.like("description", "%" + text + "%",
                        MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));

    }
    if (categoryId != null) {
        criteria.createCriteria("category").add(
                Restrictions.eq("id", categoryId));
    }
    // check if the startPrice are not null
    if (startPrice != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("price", startPrice));
    }
    // check if endPrice is not null
    if (endPrice != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("price", endPrice));
    }
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    foundAuctions = criteria.list();

    if (foundAuctions.size() > 0) {
        return foundAuctions;
    } else {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(
                "Fixed prices matching criteria can not be found");
    }
}
```

And i also get duplicate data from database. I suppose that the problem is with the mapping. Can you refer with some suggestions on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured how to get rid of the error, but i am not sure if this is the right way to do that. This is what I've done:

```
@Override
public List<Auction> getAuctionByRefineAndSearch(Integer categoryId,
        String text, Float startPrice, Float endPrice)
        throws EntityNotFoundException {

    boolean notNull = false;
    List<Auction> foundAuctions = new ArrayList<Auction>();

    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Auction.class);
    // check if the parameters are not null

    // check if the startPrice are not null
    if (startPrice != null) {
        System.out.println("startPrice=" + startPrice);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("reservedPrice", startPrice));
    }
    // check if endPrice is not null
    if (endPrice != null) {
        System.out.println("endPrice=" + endPrice);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("reservedPrice", endPrice));
    }
    // check if the text is null
    if (text != null) {
        notNull = true;
        criteria.createCriteria("item").add(
                Restrictions
                        .disjunction()
                        .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + text + "%",
                                MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
                        .add(Restrictions.like("description", "%" + text
                                + "%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
    }
    // check if categoryId is not null
    if (categoryId != null) {
        if (notNull) {
            criteria.createCriteria("category").add(
                    Restrictions.eq("id", categoryId));
        } else {
            criteria.createCriteria("item").createCriteria("category")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("id", categoryId));
        }
    }

    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    foundAuctions = criteria.list();

    if (foundAuctions.size() > 0) {
        return foundAuctions;
    } else {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(
                "Auctions matching criteria can not be found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is saying that there is no column called `price` on your `Item` class, because there isn't. You need to add a field called `price` on your `Item` class for this to work.

Other than the above issue your code looks correct for implementing those criteria. One point that may be of interest. You shouldn't be doing null checking in a DAO. That's what your service class is for. Your DAO should only be concerned with implementing your query, not having to worry about null checking.

This is just my 0.02c, but it makes your code much harder to read and therefore maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i can't add the field price on the entity Item. It is there another way of creating the criteria?